# Compute parity using AND instead of XOR?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

The author of Elements of Programming Interview poses the question "How would you compute the parity of a very large number of 64-bit words?"
Then goes on to give a brute-force solution

```
    def parity(x):
        result = 0
        while x:
            result ^= x & 1
            x >>= 1
    
        return result
```

Why do we need a XOR for brute force ? Why not simply use an AND ?

```
    def parityUsingAnd(x):
        result = 0
        while x:
            if x & 1 > 0:
                result += 1
            x = x >> 1
    
        return result % 2 == 0
```

I get the same results for a few select test cases that I checked manually, therefore, want to know if this brute-force solution is correct?

Comment: Note that you can also use `result += x & 1` and then return `result % 2 == 0`. No `if` necessary. But is addition simpler than XOR? I wouldn't say so

Comment: Also, `x>>=l` should be `x>>=1`.

Comment: This isn't a question about programming, but about basic logic. "Why do we need a XOR for brute force ? Why not simply use an AND ?" - This doesn't make any sense to ask, because the author's code **does use** `and`, in the **same way that yours does**. The XOR is used in place of the **addition**, in order to avoid having to check whether the result is even or odd later.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "This isn't a question about programming, but about basic logic" Strongly disagree. Programming is all about logic (basic or complex). I agree with the second part of your statement, and now I see why XOR was actually used. Thank You.

Comment: "Programming is all about logic " Yes , but figuring out the logic is the job of programming, not a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the same results for a few select test cases

Actually, there are differences:

- (This was fixed in an edit:) <strike>The first function has an error (likely a typo): `l` is not defined. Should be `1`.</strike>
- The functions return a different data type: respectively `int` and `bool`
- The functions return opposite results. For example, for input 0 the respective return values are 0 and True

To harmonise the second function with the first, its `return` statement should not make the comparison. It should be:

```
return result % 2
```

> Why do we need a XOR for brute force ? Why not simply use an AND ?

There are often many ways to solve a problem. But in this case they *both* use `AND`. The difference is between `XOR` and `+`. Whether `+` is "simpler" than `XOR` will be a matter of opinion. You could also say that `XOR 1` will change exactly one bit; the least significant bit. With `+ 1` there may be more bits impacted. Some could say that is actually more complex as an operation.

More objectively, there is the aspect of *auxiliary space* used by the algorithms. In the second function, the space needed for `result` is O(log log) in the worst case, while the first function "only" needs O(1) auxiliary space. Not really a problem, since O(log log ) is less memory than the memory needed to store  itself. But still, it is a difference. It can be easily solved by keeping only the least bit of `result` in each iteration of the loop, but then it comes down to performing a `XOR` operation without using that operator.

Finally -- in line with your *addition* algorithm -- Python 3.10+ has `int.bit_count`, so you can do:

```
def parity(x):
    return x.bit_count() % 2
```

Comment: Or *return x.bit_count() & 1* which is faster (Python 3.11.4)

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguity.

Let's say we have 3 disks. We're repairing Disk 1.

Both the parity disk and disk 2 have a 0 in a certain bit.

We can't tell from that whether Disk 1 had a 1 or a 0 - both would have yielded a result of 0 in the parity calculation.

There are other cases like this, but the fact that even one exists is enough to explain why AND doesn't work in my opinion.